# Get last column of data.table not working

Tags: r, data.table

I'm an R noob. So I have a data.table in a variable called `a`. I'm trying to generically get the last column. It works when I specify column 6, but it doesn't work with `ncol(a)`. Why is that?

```
class(a)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
a
   permissions size month date timestamp     file
1:  drwxr-xr-x 8192   Oct   02     14:25   to_xpn
2:  drwxr-xr-x 8192   Oct   04     10:38 from_xpn

ncol(a)
[1] 6

a[,6]
       file
1:   to_xpn
2: from_xpn

a[,ncol(a)]
[1] 6
```

Comment: See the [`data.table` FAQ - 1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num)

Comment: try `a[, ncol(a), with = FALSE]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need `with = FALSE`

```
library(data.table)

iris.dt <- data.table(iris)

iris.dt[, ncol(iris.dt), with = FALSE]


#        Species
#   1:    setosa
#   2:    setosa
#   3:    setosa
#   4:    setosa
#   5:    setosa
#  ---          
# 146: virginica
# 147: virginica
# 148: virginica
# 149: virginica
# 150: virginica
```